# Transforming a DataFrame into a Keras dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, dataset

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing about 10k 100x100 images stored in grayscale (as a (100,100,1) numpy array), along with a label for each of them (as a string, which is someone's name). I want to turn it into a Keras dataset.

I read that I can simply use `dataset = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(dataframe))`, but it doesn't work, maybe because it's a 3D numpy array? Should I reshape each 100x100 image into a 10,000 long array?

I'm trying to construct my dataset similar to the CIFAR10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can seperate out the labels from the images and then pass the images dataframe and the labels dataframe separately in a tuple to the `from_tensor_slices` function, it should work...

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images,labels))
```

I tried to recreate your issue for myself by generating random values in the shape (10000,100,100,1) as the image dataset and it seemed to work just fine on my end.

Comment: Thanks! I did something slightly different, which was separating images and labels, and then converting the (10000,) array to (10000,100,100,1), and it also seems to work fine.

Comment: A pleasure to hear it.